# Capturing coordinates of a HTML map area click event (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an image of a map of the world and it allows users to click on a specific region and add new points to it.

To achieve this I use an image map with poly coordinates to specify each clickable region and then I have some code that processes the event, associates the click with a specific region of the globe (important) and plots a point on the coordinates that the user clicked on.

The following code (using jQuery) functions perfectly in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome (v30) I can't find a way to capture the coordinates of the mouseclick relative to the parent element.
This is important because the map opens in a modal draggable window. All the event coordinates are relative to the window, but none relate to the parent offset.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("area").click(function(e){
        // IE fix - stop event propagating after initial click
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log(e);

        // Firefox
        if (firefox) {
            x = e.originalEvent.layerX;
            y = e.originalEvent.layerY
        }
        // IE
        else if (ie) {
            x = e.originalEvent.offsetX;
            y = e.originalEvent.offsetY;
        }
        // Chrome ????
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 40px; position:absolute;">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative;">
        <img src="/View/Images/maps/Globe_2.png" id="worldMap" alt="World Map" usemap="#Globe_2" style="border-style:none" />
    </div>
</div>
<map id="Globe_2" name="Globe_2">
    <area shape="poly" id="na" coords="0,0,344,1,344,46,325,61,314,75,297,80,262,118,253,155,236,179,242,208,208,216,177,223,154,226,148,244,133,259,62,260,0,260" />
    <area shape="poly" id="sa" coords="242,208,179,224,155,227,150,243,145,249,135,259,133,261,0,261,0,502,313,502,312,309,304,279,277,263,246,234" />
    <area shape="poly" id="af" coords="314,503,313,309,306,278,290,269,278,261,247,233,238,180,250,162,327,164,334,164,346,161,355,159,364,159,369,159,372,165,372,167,384,171,396,169,409,174,421,174,425,177,425,179,426,183,426,188,445,223,449,230,452,233,470,228,494,230,518,291,543,306,543,502" />
    <area shape="poly" id="eu" coords="250,161,254,156,263,118,297,81,314,76,316,75,326,61,345,47,345,0,409,0,405,73,402,74,401,76,402,79,404,84,408,90,404,95,407,97,407,100,403,100,403,104,404,108,410,109,414,115,412,118,419,119,419,121,421,122,423,124,432,125,432,130,429,132,422,135,422,138,426,139,428,139,437,144,439,148,443,149,446,155,447,160,428,162,425,176,421,173,410,173,397,168,384,170,373,166,369,158,354,158,334,163,310,163" />
    <area shape="poly" id="as" coords="494,229,470,227,452,232,447,225,427,188,426,181,425,176,429,163,449,161,446,154,443,148,439,147,437,143,427,138,425,138,423,137,423,136,427,134,433,131,433,125,432,124,423,123,421,121,420,120,420,118,413,118,415,115,410,108,405,107,404,105,404,101,408,101,408,97,405,95,409,90,404,84,401,76,403,74,406,73,410,0,776,0,776,292,775,291,718,300,703,294,689,295,671,287,652,298,627,299,544,304,519,290" />
    <area shape="poly" id="au" coords="544,305,654,299,671,289,689,297,703,295,718,301,776,293,776,502,544,502" />
    <area shape="default" id="noclick" nohref="nohref" />
</map>
```

Comment: Just get `e.pageX` and calculate it yourself based on the elements offset. Should be cross browser and not that hard.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case in Chrome when clicking an AREA element. e.pageX and e.offsetX are both the same - the position of the click relative to the window.

Comment: Of course it is, and what I'm saying is that you can use that and figure out the position of the click in the element if you subtract the elements position. That's the usual way of doing this,

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in the original post. The image is in a draggable floating Ext-js window. I don't know any way to figure out the position of the image within the document, given that it will change any time the user drags the window. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You're using jQuery, did you try `$('img').offset().top` to get the image offset

Comment: I just tried it there and that's perfect, thanks. I'll be able to work out the relative click coordinates based on that. I'm still confused as to why the relative coordinates are available in IE and Firefox's click event on the image map, but not in Chrome's.

Comment: As far as I know layerX and offsetX aren't standarized, pageX however is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @adeneo this is now resolved. Chrome doesn't provide a method to find the relative coordinates of a click event on an image map. However, using the jquery.offset() method, I can find the coordinates of my image (dynamic on the page) and work out the relative position of the click based on that.

```
clickX = event.pageX - $("#worldMap").offset().left;
clickY = event.pageY - $("#worldMap").offset().top;
```